# vm mount is empty when accessing database container

Tags: mysql, docker, virtual-machine

I use macOs, and use docker daemon inside multipass (VM), and I mount my file to VM. You can see this pic [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cuUL2oWSwwNumweXHcL_htaZ1SoCFkxX/view?usp=sharing). (btw I use ssh to connect to vm)

when I `docker-compose up` all container works fine, except `mysql` container

my file docker-compose like this

```
mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.6
    user: mysql
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: default
      MYSQL_USER: default
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/data/db:/var/lib/mysql
```

*I write `user: mysql`, because when I `docker-compose up`, it will change owner in `./docker/data/db`*

when all container start, it looks fine, I check files inside container, all there (see [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eSbnM9DlabeWYNUl-U1jBAimkZAYlKzR/view?usp=sharing))

when I open database, the all files gone (also mount is gone too) see [this image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HDhITkPTIakFSSxcb-FgDAy7HgCKjAsm/view?usp=sharing)

but if I stop mysql container, it will show again, see [this image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h83fVj_-bjebuD8dIcN4t8gm0TBUeeyv/view?usp=sharing)

you can watch [this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ArLSBCRXAUL5gefkkq2TM2Hap862uyJi/view?usp=sharing)

**My question is**,

why if an open database makes the mounted file gone? and how to fix it?

because, mysql data from `./docker/data/db` (is there a way to not use volume instead?)

***Note**: when use Docker Desktop all normal, this only happens if using docker-daemon in VM*

any one can help me?
thank you.

Comment: The PNG-format images you've included in this question can't be run, searched, or read.  Can you [edit] the question to remove all of the images?  Make sure to include a [mcve], including the application source code, actual commands you're running, and output, ass in plain text.

Comment: hi @DavidMaze Thank you for reminding me,
I have edited and just uploaded the image to gdrive

Comment: There is not enough information _in the question_ to understand your problem or answer it.

Comment: thanks @DavidMaze, I just updated my question, if something's still unclear, let's forget about this :)